# NGINX Reverse Proxy not forwarding Real-IP despite including proxy_set_header for it

Tags: python, nginx, proxy

So I have a Python application running with an NginX reverse proxy providing an SSL connection to the running app. I have configured the reverse proxy with the appropriate proxy_set_header directives to forward the $remote_addr variable to the X-Real-IP header. What I'm struggling with is that the Python application is still pulling the localhost address as the IP that is accessing the app.

This exact configuration is setup on two other servers, run by other people without problems.  I'm just not sure if there is a configuration option in the main NginX conf file that I need to modify, although neither of the other admins mentioned having this issue with their configurations.

Attached is my site configuration.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name             redacted;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/redacted.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/redacted.key;

    ssl                         on;
    ssl_session_cache           builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    access_log              /var/log/nginx/redacted.access.log;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8765;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;

        proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8765   https://redacted;

    }

}
```

Comment: Check your application if it really takes remote ip from header and not from connection. Check if your nginx isn't behind some other proxy server.

Comment: It appears that it is pulling the remoteaddr from the Request object. Like I said, I'm not familiar with Python. The other admins with the same application running have their config for NginX setup the same way and are not having this problem.